# where is the movie clip node on blender 2.83?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm on blender 2.83 and I would like to apply a shader nodes scheme to a movie clip,instead to the single frames,but it seems that it isn't where it should be. At least,according with the tutorial that I'm following,this one :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pPGR3d9WWc

Below you can see clearly that I don't have that node anymore.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are in the wrong node editor at the moment. The [*Movie Clip node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/movie_clip.html#movie-clip-node) is a *compositing node*, and is found in in the [compositor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html#introduction).

Refer to the image below:

[image]

Currently, you are in the [*shader editor*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html#shader-editor). So, just switch editors and you will find the node you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To use a movie clip as texture in a material use an Image Texture node.

Select the video as source.

[image]